# Dereferenceable iterators

Tags: c++, iterator

Is there anything in the standard that says that if `a` is a standard container, any method of `a` that returns an iterator which is not invalidated should be either dereferenceable or equal to `a.end()`?

Would it be against the standard to write a container with a method that returns an iterator which is not invalidated and is different from `a.end()` and cannot be dereferenced?

I am thinking of building an open adressing hash table where

```
it search(const K& key)
```

returns a pointer to the slot where the (key, value) pair is stored if the key is in the hash table, and is the slot where (key, value) should be inserted if key is not part of this hash table. In the second case, the iterator could not be dereferenced and would be different from `a.end()`.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There aren't that many methods that return iterators. The standard says that `begin()` returns an iterator to the first element (which implicitly means it's dereferenceable) unless the container is empty, in which case it returns `end()`. And `end()` of course returns an iterator equal to `end()`. What other methods do you have in mind, where there might be any doubt? The standard doesn't talk about arbitrary methods returning iterators - only of those methods that are required for the class to be called a container (such as `begin()` and `end()`).

Comment: In your example of `search()` - how is the caller going to be able to tell the difference between the two cases? What will the caller be allowed to do with an iterator returned by `search()`?

Comment: Standard shapes language and standard library, it does not tell anything about how you should write your own methods

Comment: @Igor: I have simplified things. The Iterator could be a class made of a pointer and a bool. The bool would be true if the the key has been found and false otherwise. If the key has been found, the user would be able to dereference the iterator. If the key has not been found he would be able to call the method insert(key, value, it) to insert the key value pair where it should be inserted (without rehashing the key).

Comment: What would happen if I increment this strange iterator, then decrement it back - do I return to the same empty slot? If I start at `begin()` and increment all the way through `end()`, do I walk over all slots (full and empty alike), or just the full ones? What does `size()` return on your container - a total number of slots, or the number of full ones? What does it mean for your container to be `empty()`?

Comment: @Igor: This stange iterator (one returned by search such that key is not in the hash table) would lead to undefined behavior if we try to do anything but: query its bool state, or using it for insertion with the same key. If we start with begin() and increments through end(), one would get all the filled slots. And size() would return the number if filled slots. The container would be empty if no slots would be filled.

Comment: Then I don't believe the standard has anything - good or bad - to say about your peculiar design, just so long as you don't pass one of those strange iterators to any function from the standard library. As far as the standard is concerned, such an iterator has a singular value (similar to a "normal" iterator that hasn't been initialized or has been invalidated). Any additional properties it may have are specific to your class, above and beyond the set of behaviors required for that class to be called a container.

Comment: Igor: Thanks. Does the standard clearly defines what a singular value is?

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.requirements.general#7

Comment: @Igor: But my strange iterator would be a singular value asosciated with a container which goes against the definition of singular value.

Comment: Doesn't really matter. It's indistinguishable from a singular value as far as the standard library is concerned.

Comment: Ok thanks for your lights and especially this link to the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Iterator is a concept introduced in the C++ standard library on top of the basic language features. You can certainly have your own type of "iterators."

For clear semantics, however, in the case of the hash table, a `search()` should probably never return an `end()`, because it always returns a valid slot (even though it may be empty).

By returning an iterator, you probably intended to try successive hash values through calling `operator++()`. In that case, it could return an `end()` when all slots (empty or not) have been exhausted (assuming that the hash table size is to remain constant).

Comment: Let's suppose you want to do memoization with a function: Value f(const Key& key). When you want to get the value for key, you first search the hash table. If the key is in the hash table, you return its corresponding value. It if is not, you compute f(key) and put it in the hash table. With std::unordered_map, I don't know a way to do that without hasing the key twice which is not good for performance.

Comment: @InsideLoop `std::unordered_map::operator[]` does this: returns a reference to existing value if the key is already in the map; or creates a new entry and returns a reference to its value component if the key was not in the map.

Comment: @Igor: I don't know any way to hash the key only once to do what I want with std::unordered_map. If you call `operator[]` you hash the key and you have no way to know if the key was already in the hash table.

Comment: @InsideLoop Another technique - call `insert()` with a dummy value (e.g. default-constructed). It would either insert a new entry and return an iterator to it (which you can then use to save a real value), or return an iterator to an existing entry, without replacing its value. In either case, along with the iterator it returns  a `bool` indicating which of the two cases has taken place.

Comment: @hvd: You are correct, the C++ standard library is also defined in the C++ standard. What I meant was that it is a separate part from the language proper (rather than say the keywords and basic types). I'm editing the answer to reflect it. Thanks.

Comment: @Tandetnik: You are right. I never thought of that. Even though you need to have a dummy value which is very fast to construct, it sounds like a good solution. The interface to std::unordered_map looks so unintuitive to me.

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question.

Comment: @InsideLoop: Under the hood `std::unordered_map::operator[]` probably does multiple hash evaluations (and is based on a variable-sized hash table). You could extend the class with a `search()` to first do a `find()` for the `bool` you want to return.

Comment: @Edy: I want an open addressing hash table anyway for performance reason. But I am trying to figure out which interface to use. For std::unordered_map, I don't see any reason why [] would do multiple hash evaluations.